Chrome Extension to change download settings
I'm trying to create a simple extension with button/icon with option enable/disable (on/off). This extension will change chrome settings about downloads/"Ask where to save each file before downloading". I was scrolling ref. API from chrome extension, but I found nothing about it. Maybe someone knows something about it? I need to change it quickly based on daily usage.

Apparently it's not controllable via API. You can suggest it in https://crbug.com and maybe they'll implement it in 10 years.
